# How to prevent spring-boot from trying to load application.properties instead of our own defined properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I'm running into a strange problem while migrating a old spring-boot service to use externalized configuration.
The service in local and server side keep trying to load application.properties eventhough we provide the profile.
I even tried to force "spring.config.name" to the value we need via System.setProperty("spring.config.name", getPropertiesPath()), but this still doesn't work and I would prefer not to do it that way.

Here the short version of the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.mydomain.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Here the modified Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    protected static final String CONTAINER_ENVIRONMENT_KEY = "ENVIRONMENT";
    private static final String CDS_SERVICE_CHARTS_PROPERTIES_PATH  = "server.properties";
    private static final String APPLICATION_LOCAL_PROPERTIES_PATH  = "application-local.properties";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", getPropertiesPath());
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    protected static String getPropertiesPath() {
        return StringUtils.isBlank(System.getenv(CONTAINER_ENVIRONMENT_KEY)) ? APPLICATION_LOCAL_PROPERTIES_PATH : CDS_SERVICE_CHARTS_PROPERTIES_PATH;
    }
}
```

I've run through all the possible source following this properties order from springboot documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config
and there no other config that we use except for testing.
On top of that there no reference of application.properties anywhere in the code, I assume there a lib that we used that might cause the problem.
I can really see where the service try to get application.properties instead of what we provided.

Note we did the same process of using a externalized configuration in other services and didn't have that problem.

Here the Full trace of the exception on run time, note that there no reference to our app in it.

```
2023-03-30T17:02:23,073  INFO [main]   637:Application                              : The following 1 profile is active: "local" 
2023-03-30T17:02:26,586  WARN [main]   591:AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.mydomain.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist 
2023-03-30T17:02:26,848 ERROR [main]   821:SpringApplication                        : Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.mydomain.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.mydomain.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:462) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:279) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:303) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:303) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ... 13 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59414', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging we found out that a library, that the project was using, had a SpringConfig that required the application.properties file through a @PropertySource. Since this should not be required we added ignoreResourceNotFound.

Previous code

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
```

New code

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Hope this will help anyone who has a similar problem.